# After rendering the canvas by html2canvas, css applied on HTML classes is not getting applied

Tags: html2canvas

Issue:
 I was applying `HTML2Canvas` on an element on button click. On rendering the canvas, the CSS styles applied on HTML elements with `Class selectors` were not getting applied.

Eg: Prior to the `HTML2Canvas` application on an element, the footer and other parts of the page looks good, but once HTML2Canvas is applied, the page breaks as the styles on the class selectors were not being applied.

Links: http://cyberbel.com/wishes/